# Angular Selective Transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does anyone know a way to have a directive that can transclude the body of the directive selectively?

For example, if I have the following div and directive of myWrapper.

```
<div data-my-wrapper="foo">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

I'd like to have code in my directive that is like this pseudo code.

```
if (foo.locked) {
   // user a static template saying that the item is locked.
}
else {
   // Tranclude the body content
}
```

Is there a way to direct to the directive what content should be transcluded?  Or is there a recommended way to have the equivalent of a if/then/else that could allow me to swap out the content instead of the body of the element that the directive sits in?

Comment: You might be looking for the transclude linking function (i.e. fifth argument to the directive `link` function) to gain access to transcluded content to do what you need to do. Here's a quick demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwAXF/).

Comment: @miqid - that is what I was looking for!  Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks, I never knew there was another param after controller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gain access to transcluded content inside the `link` function of a directive by using making use of the fifth argument, which happens to be a transclude linking function. Remember also to set the `transclude` property of the directive.

```
function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }
```

Here's a crude demonstration of the transclude linking function at work: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwAXF/).

Glad that helped.

**NOTE:**

Please be aware that if you're using a version of AngularJS prior to 1.2.x that the transclude linking function is instead available as the third argument to the `compile` property of a directive. This has since been deprecated as pointed out by the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile).